# Selected implementation

Tags: arrays, data-structures

If each element of an array RM,with 10 rows and 20 columns, stored in row major order, takes four bytes of space, where the first element of RM starts at 100, what is the address of RM[5][3] and RM[9][19]?

Answer (score 0):

So here's an array with 20 columns and 10 rows (elements start at 0):

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 ...
40 41 42 ...
60 61 ...
...
```

You spot a very simple pattern! So: What`s the index of`R[5][3]`(i.e. the element of`R` in the fifth row, third column?

And: If each element occupies four byte, where will `R[5][3]` be?

Note: As far as I know, C stores arrays in row-major order (even more: on many systems, a simple `int` occupies four or eight byte). Thus, you could use C to conduct some experiments that help you in finding the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the zero-based arrays common to current programming languages:

```
RM[5][3] : 100 + (5 * 20 * 4) + (3 * 4) = 512

RM[9][19] : 100 + (9 * 20 * 4) + (19 * 4) = 896
```